# C# - Windows Forms - Media Player

Tags: c#, winforms, media-player

I am a creating a movie theater program that blanks other screens and plays movie file on 3rd monitor (TV).  Does anyone have a suggestion for a media player.  Media Player is giving a ActiveX error and I do not want the border with the play pause and fast forward buttons etc.  It is windows forms so I don't have Media Element. Any suggestions for a different media player. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change [Media player](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `uimode` property to `none`

```
player.uiMode = "none";
```

> Windows Media Player is embedded without controls, and with only the
>   video or visualization window displayed.